# Какие аналоги OpenMP есть для Python?

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, openmp

Какие аналоги OpenMP (параллельные цикли и блокирование переменных)  есть для Python?

Comment: В Cython есть поддержка собственно OpenMP. Однако это не особо полезная вещь

Comment: Отвечать не буду, напишу коммент: **GIL** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obt-vMVdM8s

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/tbb4py